# Query fail Oracle but working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, ora-00923

I have a query that runs perfectly n SQL server but in Oracle, I get the following error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

```
SELECT  
MyApps.AppConfigurationId, 
MyApps.GUID, 
MyApps.AppName, 
MyApps.BinaryData, 
MyApps.Color1, 
MyApps.UserCreatorName, 
MyApps.CreatedAt,  
MyApps.UserUpdaterName, 
MyApps.UpdatedAt, 
MyApps.UserPublisherName, 
MyApps.LastPublishedAt, 
MyApps.AppConfigStateId, 
MyApps.AppConfigStateLabel 
FROM 
(  
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."ID" 
            ORDER BY LastestPublishInfo."PUBLISHEDAT" DESC 
        ) AS RowNum, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."ID" AS AppConfigurationId, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."GUID", 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."NAME" AS AppName, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPICON1"."BINARYDATA", 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_COLORPA1"."COLOR1", 
        UserCreator."NAME" AS UserCreatorName, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."CREATEDAT",  
        UserUpdater."NAME" AS UserUpdaterName, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."UPDATEDAT", 
        LastestPublishInfo.PublisherName AS UserPublisherName , 
        LastestPublishInfo."PUBLISHEDAT" AS LastPublishedAt, 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."APPCONFIGSTATEID", 
         "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON20"."LABEL" AS AppConfigStateLabel            

    FROM     "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266" JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON20" 
                ON ( "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."APPCONFIGSTATEID" =  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON20"."ID" AND 
                     "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."PARENTAPPCONFIGID" IS NULL AND 
                     "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."ISACTIVE" = 1 
                   ) 
            JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSSYS_USER_T266" UserCreator 
                ON ( "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."CREATEDBY" = UserCreator."ID") 
            LEFT JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSSYS_USER_T266" UserUpdater 
                ON ( "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."UPDATEDBY" = UserCreator."ID") 
            LEFT JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_COLORPA1" 
                ON( "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."COLORPALETTEID" =  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_COLORPA1"."ID") 
            LEFT JOIN               
                ( 
                    SELECT   "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16"."APPCONFIGURATIONID", 
                             "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16"."PUBLISHEDAT", 
                            UserPublisher."NAME" AS PublisherName 
                    FROM     "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16" LEFT JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSSYS_USER_T266" UserPublisher 
                                ON ( "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16"."PUBLISHEDBY" = UserPublisher."ID") 
                    WHERE    "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16"."PUBLISHEDAT" IS NOT NULL  
                            AND 
                             "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON16"."ISACTIVE" = 0 
                             
                ) LastestPublishInfo 
                ON (LastestPublishInfo.AppConfigurationId =  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."ID") 
            LEFT JOIN  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPICON1" 
                ON(  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPICON1"."APPCONFIGURATIONID" =  "OSADMIN_OSDEV1"."OSUSR_4BQ_APPCON15_T266"."ID" ) 
) MyApps 
WHERE MyApps.RowNum = 1 
ORDER BY  
MyApps.UpdatedAt DESC
```

I already tried to check syntax follow some articles but I'm not able to solve it.
Added " around de the aliases, tried to replace attribute names in the subquery not to match the parent but nothing worked.
Hope you could help me with this since I went to the point I have no clue about what to try next!
Cheers

Comment: I don't think Oracle accepts `[`, `]`, `{`, or `}` as parts of identifiers or delimiters. You better use double quotes `"` or improve the table and column names.

Comment: Yeah that is not valid oracle syntax.

Comment: Sorry, you can ignore that since I took this from my own platform. I fixed the executed query on the post.

Comment: Your query looks good. What version of Oracle are you using? In any case your query would benefit from the use of table aliases. It's not easy to read or to debug. Can you provide a SQL Fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/ ?

Comment: We're using Oracle 12 12.1.0.2.v17. Any tip about what can be causing issues in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following web: https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler
I tryed your SQL and got the same error as you.
I then started simplifing it up to:

SELECT 1 AS RowNum
FROM  blah

and still getting the same error.
I think RowNum is a reserved word in Oracle, you can not use it as a field alias.

Comment: That was exactly the issue..Being the RowNumber a reserved word in Oracle. Thank you very much. Cheers